# Angular chain promise immediately after the first

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have two factories : `getPosition` gets current location, `geoCoding` uses google reverse geocoding to get the city name. Both of them use $q.defer() and both of them write the data received to local storage. I want to chain them on page load. So the position should write the current position to local storage and then geocoding should **immediately** decode it. I tried to chain them like that:

```
   getPosition.get().then(function(geoInfo){
    $scope.$storage.geoInfo = geoInfo;
    return geoCoding.get().then(function(city){
      $scope.$storage.city = city;
      $scope.city = $scope.$storage.city;
    },function(reason){
      alert("Geocoding error: " + reason);
    })
  }, function(reason){
    alert("Location error: " + reason);
  });
```

But this way i only get the position on initial page load, and i get the city on page refresh. I've read the documentation and searched stackoverflow, but i'm still missing something. How to chain the calls so that both of them are received at page load?

Comment: The promises look correct. How are you accessing city? Are you doing something like `$scope.$watch('city', useCity);`? Or are you trying to chain another `.then` to these results?

Comment: What is `$storage`? Any chance it's operations are asynchronous?

Comment: @DRobinson I only access the city in the code above. $scope.city=$scope.$storage.city; That's it. If the promises are correct, shouldn't the city load into the local storage immediately? When I look in the chrome console local storage doesn't update on page load.

Comment: @Phil It's ngStorage module. Why would it be asynchronous? Although i should check on that.

Comment: @woolywhale I'm not familiar with that one which is why I asked. I just checked it out and it doesn't appear to be async.

Comment: @Phil Sorry if I seemed rude, I didn't mean to be. Also the problem solved itself all of a sudden. I didn't change anything in the code and it started to work just like it should. Super strange.

Comment: No offence taken. I feel like you'll have better luck explicitly passing information to your services via arguments (eg `geoCoding.get(geoInfo)`) rather than relying on a shared resource like `$localStorage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resolved when I used the data received from the first call directly, without writing to local storage. I don't know why it works only like that, but anyway, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested this but maybe you could try doing something like this:

```
getPosition
    .get()
    .then(function(geoInfo){
      $scope.$storage.geoInfo = geoInfo;
      return geoCoding.get();
    })
    .then(function(city){
      $scope.$storage.city  = city;
      $scope.city           = $scope.$storage.city;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      alert("Error: " + error);
    });
```

Not sure if you can do this with `$q` but I've used this with `bluebird`. It seems counter to the main benefit of promises to be adding more `then()` calls within `then()` calls. It's just the same as the callback hell promises were meant to prevent. So I'd be surprised if you can't chain all your promises like above.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The call to geocoding works if i use the geo info from the first call directly, without writing to local storage. Thank you for the answer anyway.